# Cannot Push Array of Values to a Json Typescript Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a object

```
formErrors = {
    'name': [],
    'age' : []
  };
```

I am adding validation errors to it Dynamically from a Template Driven form . 
But when i try to push values to the key it throws errors and when i just assign it a normal string it works.

```
onValueChanged(data?: any) {
    if (!this.f) { return; }
    const form = this.f.form;

    for (const field in this.formErrors) {
      // clear previous error message (if any)
      this.formErrors[field] = '';
      const control = form.get(field);

      if (control && control.dirty && !control.valid) {
        const messages = this.validationMessages[field];
        for (const key in control.errors) {
          this.formErrors[field].push(messages[key]); // error line
          this.formErrors[field] += messages[key] + ' '; // this works if the change object struct to name :''
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

The error in console is

```
TemplateDrivenComponent.html:10 ERROR TypeError: this.formErrors[field].push is not a function
    at 

    TemplateDrivenComponent.webpackJsonp.178.TemplateDrivenComponent.onValueChanged (template-driven.component.ts:46)
        at template-driven.component.ts:29
        at SafeSubscriber.schedulerFn [as _next] (core.es5.js:3840)
        at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:236)
        at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:185)
        at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:125)
        at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:89)
        at EventEmitter.Subject.next (Subject.js:55)
        at EventEmitter.emit (core.es5.js:3814)
        at FormGroup.AbstractControl.updateValueAndValidity (forms.es5.js:2601)
        at FormControl.AbstractControl.updateValueAndValidity (forms.es5.js:2605)
        at FormControl.setValue (forms.es5.js:2948)
        at DefaultValueAccessor.onChange (forms.es5.js:1752)
        at DefaultValueAccessor._handleInput (forms.es5.js:619)
        at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (TemplateDrivenComponent.html:10)
```

Comment: because u have intitalized it to a string `this.formErrors[field] = ''`;

push works on array & Not String.

Comment: You are replacing your arrays with strings `this.formErrors[field] = '';` I think you meant an empty array to "clear errors" `[]`.

Comment: nope i want to push these error messages to the array , and the space ' ' is only to give spacing when i was not using array now i want to use array

Comment: @ParthGhiya thanks such a silly mistake

Comment: Your last line works because you are concatenating a string, but if you want it to be an array to push to, then you need to clear it by reinitialise get as an empty array `this.formErrors[field] = []`

Comment: @Rahul added as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because u have intitalized it to a string

```
this.formErrors[field] = '';
```

push works on array & Not String

change that line to

```
this.formErrors[field] = [];
```